# Eclipse cannot find library

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a problem with adding library to my c project in eclipse. I have libraries *.lib which I have to add to my project. I've added them in "paths and symbols-> libraries" (only  names of the libraries) and the path to the libraries directory in "paths and symbols-> library path)

I do everything as it is in the user guide but linker shows that he cannot find this libraries. Any ideas?

Comment: You must also add linker flags like `-l<library-name>` for each library you use. For example, `-lACE` for `libACE.so`.

Comment: when I add library to paths and symbols I have it automatically in the c/c++ build/linker/settings and there is a full directory to the library

Comment: Indeed. I posted what I found in answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### In short:

Edit library from full path to library name like:

```
<path>/lib<name>.so to <name>
```

This will lead to linking with flag `-l<name>` which is right.

---

I got the same issue as you by following to your steps. I used ACE library for testing.

- I added ACE library to `Project/Properties/C/C++ General/Paths and
  Symbols/Libraries`
- I added path to libraries to `Project/Properties/C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Library Paths`

After that, in `Project/Properties/C/C++ Build/Settings/Libraries` I've got:

- `/usr/local/lib/libACE.so` as library.
- `/usr/local/lib` as library path.

That lead to linking with flag `-l/usr/local/lib/libACE.so` which isn't right. As I know, there shouldn't be `lib` prefix when using `-l` flag.

When I changed `/usr/local/lib/libACE.so` to `ACE` in `Project/Properties/C/C++ Build/Settings/Libraries`, linking went normally.

---

This is the test code I compiled:

```
#include <ace/Time_Value.h>

int main() {

    ACE_Time_Value t;
    t.msec(1000);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still cannot find this library